# How to git checkout -b from two weeks ago or from an specific date?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am trying to checkout and old version of my code from the `master` branch and I am doing as follow:

```
git checkout -b master_de1974 `git rev-list -n 1 --before="5 days ago" master`
```

Is that the right command? How I can be sure if I am getting the old code instead the new one?

Comment: You should checkout from a commit to be sure to be on the exact snapshot of your code. You can look "where" you are on the tree by typing `git log -n3` it will show you the last three commit from the current position. So you should see commits at the expected date or before if your command worked

Comment: @olibiaz and then having the commit ID what's the right command to run?

Comment: With `git log` you get the SHA1 of the commit. Then just `git checkout -b <new-branch> <sha1>`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should refer to a specific commit to be sure you are at the exact "position", version of your code you expect.

To find the commit number, you can check on github/bitbucket or whatever is your remote repository. If you have not "UI repository", you can list your commit by using the `git log` command, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log, for example:

```
git log -n10
```

will display the 10 last commits that have been saved to the tree. Once you find your commit,you can create your new branch from here:

```
git checkout -b master_de1974 a9c146a09505837ec03b
```

Where *a9c146a09505837ec03b* is your commit number. Then you can be sure you are on the good date/commit, by typing again

```
git log -n1
```

It should show you the commit you choose to be back to.

Comment: But what If you are not looking for *your* commits but from repository?

Comment: The command `git log -n` return all the commits on the branch, so its not only your commits, but all the commits that are in the branch you are currently in.

Answer (score -1):

I think this does it (not my answer), I tried it out and seems to work:
https://gist.github.com/viktorkelemen/5101763

git checkout $(git rev-list -n1 --before="2 weeks ago" master)

Comment: This is essentially the same code as in the question.